# Glyph metrics in SWT?

Tags: java, fonts, swt

Given an SWT graphics context and a font with a specific size, how can I get the glyph metrics of a single character?

In other words, I'm looking for an equivalent of `java.awt.font.GlyphVector`.

As a workaround, I'm currently loading the same font via AWT to get this glyph vector - is there a better way using SWT APIs only?

Comment: Does [`FontData`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fgraphics%2FFontData.html) have the functionality you are looking for?

Comment: No, it doesn't. `FontData` only depends on the font but not on any of the glyphs or characters of the string type constructor argument. Looking at individual glyphs, the height of `a` will be different from the height of `X`.

Answer (score 0):

If width and height is sufficient for your purposes then you can use `GC.textExtent()` to measure any String's rectangular area with a particular font.

Comment: I need the height of a given character. The height returned by `textExtent` only depends on the font and is determined by the largest character(s). See my comment above.